# Unknown Action, The action '1' could not be found for SubjectsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Mamboo!

Am new to RoR and using Lynda Ruby on Rails 4 Essential Training.
I keep getting " Unknown Action, The action '1' could not be found for SubjectsController" After pressing "Update Subject", on my edit page. I think it can not find update function! What is missing here?

Route.rb

```ruby
Rails.application.routes.draw do

   resources :subjects do get 'index', on: :collection end

   match ':controller(/:action(/id))', :via => [:get, :post]
end
```

subjects_controller.rb

```ruby
class SubjectsController < ApplicationController

  layout false

  def index
    @subjects = Subject.sorted
  end

  def show
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @subject = Subject.new({:name => "Default"})
  end

  def create
    @subject = Subject.new(subject_params)
    if @subject.save
      flash[:notice] = "Subject Created Successfully"
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
      render('new')    
    end
  end

  def edit
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
    if @subject.update_attributes(subject_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Subject Updated Successfully"
      redirect_to(:action => 'show')
    else
      render('edit')    
    end
  end

  def delete
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
    @subject.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Subject Destroyed Successfully"
    redirect_to(:action => "index")
  end

  private
  def subject_params
    params.require(:subject).permit(:name, :position, :visible)
  end

end
```

edit.html.erb

```
<%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'show'}, :class => 'back-link') %>
<div>
    <h2>Update Subjects</h2>
        <%= form_for(:subject, :url => {:action => "update", :id => @subject.id}) do |f| %>
        <table summary="Subject form field">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <td><%= f.text_field(:name) %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Position</th>
                <td><%= f.text_field(:position) %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Visbile</th>
                <td><%= f.text_field(:visible) %></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <div class="form-buttons">
        <%= f.submit("Update Subject") %>
        </div>      
    <% end %>
</div>
```

rake routes

```html
$ rake routes
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
    sections GET    /sections(.:format)          sections#index
             POST   /sections(.:format)          sections#create
 new_section GET    /sections/new(.:format)      sections#new
edit_section GET    /sections/:id/edit(.:format) sections#edit
     section GET    /sections/:id(.:format)      sections#show
             PATCH  /sections/:id(.:format)      sections#update
             PUT    /sections/:id(.:format)      sections#update
             DELETE /sections/:id(.:format)      sections#destroy
       pages GET    /pages(.:format)             pages#index
             POST   /pages(.:format)             pages#create
    new_page GET    /pages/new(.:format)         pages#new
   edit_page GET    /pages/:id/edit(.:format)    pages#edit
        page GET    /pages/:id(.:format)         pages#show
             PATCH  /pages/:id(.:format)         pages#update
             PUT    /pages/:id(.:format)         pages#update
             DELETE /pages/:id(.:format)         pages#destroy
    subjects GET    /subjects(.:format)          subjects#index
             POST   /subjects(.:format)          subjects#create
 new_subject GET    /subjects/new(.:format)      subjects#new
edit_subject GET    /subjects/:id/edit(.:format) subjects#edit
     subject GET    /subjects/:id(.:format)      subjects#show
             PATCH  /subjects/:id(.:format)      subjects#update
             PUT    /subjects/:id(.:format)      subjects#update
             DELETE /subjects/:id(.:format)      subjects#destroy
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the `:via => [:get, :post]` on yout match route is interfering with the routing. Also, you don't need `do get 'index', on: :collection end` on your resource route there, as `index` is already included as a resource. The default Rails resources are: index, show, new, edit, these four as get methods, and then create, update and delete as create, put and delete methods, respectively.

Comment: did you tried to run bundle exec rake routes ?

Comment: Thanks @Rodrigo, it worked but now i get a new Routing Error, "No route matches [POST] "/subjects/1"

Comment: @knotito.. yes i have run bundle exec rake routes, what then?

Comment: then you see all generated routes, maybe you need to set the resource after the match

Answer (score 2):

No need  to specify **match ':controller(/:action(/id))', :via => [:get, :post]** in the routes. **resources :subjects** will give u route for all new, create, update, show & delete actions. Try this

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   resources :subjects
end
```

Comment: Thanks @pulkit21, it worked but now i get a new Routing Error, "No route matches [POST] "/subjects/1"

Comment: @Sieg can you please post your route file here ?

Comment: Yes, I can post it. Problem solve by Rodrigo but if u can find anything wrong in my route file please just let me know as am still learning here.

Comment: @Sieg routes are looking perfect

Comment: @Sieg  As Rodrigo mentioned try using `<%= form_for(@subject) do |f| %>` in your form

Answer (score 1):

As pulkit21 already stated, you don't need that `match` in your routes. That works for some specific cases, but in general this is usually hacky code that can be avoided with the correct usage of **resource** routing.

Removing that line in your routes file will then give you the error `"No route matches [POST] "/subjects/1"`. While I don't fully understand why this happens, I do know that the `form_for` helper don't need to have  the `:url` parameter set. As a matter of fact, when you use the **rails scaffold** to generate a controller and views, it uses a single form on a partial file for both the **new** and **edit** pages. It can do that because it can detect if a object is a **new record** (don't have an ID yet, so call CREATE) or is an existing record (already has a database ID, so call PUT to update).

In your case, Rails seems to be misunderstanding the `:action => "update"` part and instead of routing this to the PUT method (which will call the **update** method on your controller), is routing it to POST.

Try changing your `form_for` to this:

```
<%= form_for(@subject) do |f| %>
```

It's more elegant, readable and simple, and has the advantage of being able to work for both new and edit forms.

Comment: @Sieg whatever is saying is right. Because as he sated there is a common form for both **new** and **edit action**

Comment: Glad I could help :) If this indeed solved your problem, can you please mark it later as the accepted answer? Thanks!